# How to have Liberty Profile eagerly load apps on startup

Tags: websphere-liberty

Liberty Profile is loading EARs and WARs we deploy to it only when the server receives it's first request.  How can we tell it to eagerly load applications upon server start?

We're using the latest 8.5.5 WLP.

Thanks,

Stu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure the WebContainer to fully initialize the application prior to the first request by adding the following to your server.xml:

```
<webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>
```

Comment: just wonder is there same property for normal WAS profile, which I could set to false too? for all apps at once

Comment: I do not believe full profile WAS has the concept of deferring application initialization until the first request, so this property should not be necessary.